# How to make background transitions?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, css-transitions, transition

I want to make background transitions or animation like Paytm when any transaction is processed or waiting for to complete it.

I have no idea, how should I make it work. It will greatly help if anyone can let me know. How to achieve this.

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried. Without giving it a try, it's difficult to identify the issue/problems.

Answer (score -1):

for Animations you can try with some predefined java script library's like Jquery ,JQueryUI

[Jquery Animation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

[JqueryUI Effects](https://jqueryui.com/effect/)